# Proper SE site to ask about the "Flying Spaghetti Monster"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the proper SE site to ask the following question?

> I was reading the [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) and this question came
>   in my mind:
>
> Maybe in the middle east this kind of action happen before, do you know
>   any similar action to the religion in this area of earth?
>
> If yes, What would be the projection of the spaghetti religion
>   elements on it? ( cor example pirates on it or ...?
>
> And what would be the evolution of this similar actions during the
>   time?

Comment: Probably no site for that "question". Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. PS As a start, google 'site:stackexchange.com "flying spaghetti"' etc. Then google advanced google search.

Comment: [Should we include parody religions like the Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/351/561)

Comment: It was talked about adding to the scope of Mythology.SE, but there's only 1 answer and the score hardly makes it conclusive either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the correct site might be [Mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com). In fact, there's already [a answer there that is relevant to the "Spaghetti Monster"](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/are-there-any-gods-who-are-in-a-different-species-than-humans/1919#1919).

Look [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for a list of Stack Exchange sites if you don't agree.

Comment: Welcome to Meta. Downvotes here are part of the weather, being mad at them won't help. It's just **one single** downvote; I wouldn't be surprised if somebody here hates the FSM cult with a passion (which IMHO is understandable) and downvotes everything mentioning it (which is less understandable, but [people are people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzGnX-MbYE4)).

Comment: Or felt the question wasn't in good faith (no pun intended)  and strongly felt it shouldn't have been answered. I do feel, at least, that this answer was in good faith

Comment: I think the best site is indeed mythology and folklore. Some years ago we had a discussion about whether it would be on topic. I think as long as the question is well researched and written it shouldn't be that much of a problem. If we can find answers to those questions I cannot guarantee.